# Filtering histograms using Crosstalk and Plotly without using the `group` argument

Tags: r, plotly, crosstalk

I'm creating a project where I'm hoping to embed an interactive histogram into an html page generated from an R Markdown document. Because of the costs associated with the number of interactive histograms and the potential volume of usage, Shiny is not a feasible approach for this project, so I'm attempting to embed an html widget for an interactive histogram that can be filtered using [Crosstalk](https://rstudio.github.io/crosstalk/index.html) and [Plotly](https://plotly-r.com). So far, I've been able to create a filterable histogram when using the `group` argument in `ggplot(aes())` (reprex included below). Ultimately, I would like to use multiple variables to filter the histogram, which would cause problems if I'm using the `group` argument.

Is there a way that I can filter histograms using Crosstalk and Plotly without using the `group` argument?

Thanks!

```r
library(crosstalk)
library(plotly)
library(reprex)

shared_mtcars <- SharedData$new(mtcars)
bscols(widths = c(3, NA),
       list(
         filter_checkbox("cyl", "Cylinders", shared_mtcars, ~cyl, inline = TRUE)
       ),
       plotly::ggplotly(shared_mtcars %>% 
                          ggplot(aes(x = mpg, group = factor(cyl))) + 
                          geom_histogram(fill = "pale green",
                                         color = "black") + 
                          theme(legend.position = "none"))
)
```